# position relative div below fixed element

Tags: html, css

i have a fixed div at the top of the page. The height of that one is dynamic. I now need to position/float a relative div below that one.. How would i acheive that?

---

fixed (.intro)

---

relative (.test)

---

the html is basically two divs under each other. intro has position fixed and test has position relative.

```
    $(function(){
    var shrinkHeader = 300;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
        if(scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
            $('.intro').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else {
            $('.intro').removeClass('shrink');
        }
    });
    function getCurrentScroll() {
        return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
});
$('.test').css('margin-top',$('.intro').height());
```

Comment: please post your code (html and css) attemps so we can help you

Comment: If you do not know the height of of the fixed element there will be no way with CSS only. You will have to measure the height of the fixed elment and give the relative element a margin-top with the that height. You can not float a fixed element also. Please post some of your code in order to understand your problem. Maybe you don't need to use `position:fixed`.

Comment: What did you try first? Is there any piece of code where people can start of with?

Comment: with the given code the height of the fixed element will be measured and given as a margin-top correctly. What is the issue with it? Do you want the relative element always to be visibile? Please descibe what you want to achieve

Comment: I've created a fiddle of your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qqHLG/

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the blue content never ever should go under the header z-wise.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qqHLG/2/

Comment: Then you want two fixed elements. http://jsfiddle.net/qqHLG/3/